# Replacing values in several columns with values from another table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a database of NBA basketball. In it are two different tables, one has info on games that have been played and the other table has player information.

In the Game_Detail table, I have the teams, game date, and scores for each team. I also have 10 columns with the 5 starting players from each team.

```
Game_Detail Table

Date   HomeTeam   AwayTeam   H_Pts   A_Pts   H1   H2   H3   H4   H5   A1   A2   A3   A4   A5
1/1    ORL        BOS        100     99      1    22   32   55   692  12   33   55   333  90
```

In the 10 columns H1 through A5, each row has a player ID.

In the Player_Detail table with player information, there is the player ID as well.

```
Player_Detail Table

player_id   name   height   weight
```

For every row of H1 through A5 in the first table, the Game_Detail table, I want to replace the player_id with the weight of the player (one of the columns in the Player Detail table).

What is the best way to go about doing this? I'm a SQLite/SQL new user so not sure on best practice as it's a large file. The code I have tried so far to run this is not working at all.

Also, does the command change at all if I want to use name instead of weight (seeing as it's a different type, string instead of integer)?

Comment: You really want to change the data of `game_detail` or just a query that outputs the weight instead of the ID but doesn't touch the data? Keep in mind, if you replace the IDs with the weight you don't longer know who played in a game. So changing the data seems not a wise thing to do.

Comment: I suppose either one works. I am working on a duplicate of the original database so I'm not making any permanent changes with the method I was on...I figured having 10 extra columns with the player ID still there might be a bit slow later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (a lot of) joins.

```
SELECT gd01.date,
       gd01.hometeam,
       gd01.awayteam,
       gd01.h_pts,
       gd01.a_pts,
       pd01.weight,
       pd02.weight,
       ...
       pd09.weight
       pd10.weight
       FROM game_detail gd01
            LEFT JOIN player_detail pd01
                      ON gd01.h1 = pd01.player_id
            LEFT JOIN player_detail pd02
                      ON gd01.h2 = pd02.player_id
            ...
            LEFT JOIN player_detail pd09
                      ON gd01.a4 = pd09.player_id
            LEFT JOIN player_detail pd10
                      ON gd01.a5 = pd10.player_id;
```

If you want another detail just change the column references, e.g. from `weight` to `name`.